# Do rail gun systems require high voltage?

Tags: resistance, electromagnetism, ohms-law, internal-resistance

I couldn't justify, as to why most rail-gun examples I found would have high current and high voltage. When the rails & projectile can be designed to have low resistance by varying the volume of those components.

If capacitors are used, having them parallel also reduces the ESR's contribution to the total resistance.

I'm curious why many designs would have high voltage ratings, when the objective is to have high current, and the resistance can be reduced by adjusting the component's volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm curious why many designs would have high voltage ratings, when the objective is to have high current

That's true, the force exerted on the projectile only depends on current, not voltage.

But... we want the current to go from zero to "a lot" **very quickly**. If the current ramps up too slowly then the projectile will not get full acceleration at the beginning. Optimum current delivery should expend all the energy in the caps and transfer as much energy as possible to the projectile. Any energy left in the caps at the end of the shot is essentially wasted.

I have no idea what the optimum current profile is. If rail melting is an issue, it would make sense to use lower current at the beginning and increase current as the projectile picks up speed, as higher speed would spread the heat over more rail area.

However... we're going to have a huge current step, which means huge di/dt, and this means inductance is an issue:

\$ \frac{di}{dt} = \frac{E}{L} \$

Let's consider the circuit, this is going to be a "wet finger in the wind" level of precision... Inductance of the capacitor bank and wiring... something like a 5m x 50cm square loop... 5µH. Okay, let's round this up to 10µH.

The US Navy's railgun shoots at about 2km/s, with a 10m barrel this means acceleration time should be 10ms. We'd like the current to ramp up much quicker than that, say 100µs.

With 1000V, di/dt = E/L = 100M A/s, and over 100µs this reaches 10kA.

You can input any number you like into this calculation, especially if you manage to find the real numbers from a real railgun... but IMO the main reason to have high voltage is going to be the need for very high di/dt versus inductance.

Comment: That's a spot on analysis, thanks! I thought there would be enough time for the current to reach at maximum and I didn't consider the LR-aspect. It all depends on the requirements & constraints of the design, it makes sense to have the CAP-bank at high voltage to assure high current is reached in a short time and manage with the inductive variations.  I worked on a simple set-up that can deliver high current with low applied voltage but that would take quite a few seconds to reach it's max-current also, based on the design heating produced could cause fusing &/or possible welding.

Answer (score 1):

In a genuine "rail gun" the sliding bullet or sabot is a conductive shunt across two low resistance tracks. The track acts as a single shorted turn with the generated field acting in the direction which accelerates the shorting strip "up the barrel".

To maximise projectile energy the overriding aim is maximum current for the available energy source. This requires using the lowest resistance* path practically possible. Reducing the current "by design" makes no sense. * Actually lowest impedance as reactive components alter voltage and current rise-times.

Practical aspects for a low resistance path such as available volume, conductor profile, track conductivity reduce the current that can be achieved for a given available energy and voltage. The only (or main) path to higher current is then higher voltage.

Comment: Could you clarify the last paragraph? I couldn't understand how the increase of the conductor's cross-sectional area would not reduce the applied voltage and increase the current(assuming that the applied power is the same). Purely applying Ohm's law, and assuming it's a DC-circuit.

Comment: @Axtil Note " ... such as **AVAILABLE** ..." -> We are in agreement :-). I'm saying that real world  issues will limit how much we can increase track width and thickness, how large the assembly can be has an upper limit, increasing size affects inductance and sabot size and ..., etc. When, at a given voltage,  you have reached the performance limits set by all the other factors, increasing voltage will give you more current and so more performance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful but the rail gun I made used a 1 farad capacitor bank at 16 volts 500 or so amps total and it didn't shoot that well at first but upon changing the rails to copper coils it completely exceeded my expectations of a mere 15J of force on the projectile to a completely insane 60J of force so if you are having trouble try using coils as rails.